# Work with keyboard via Win Api

Tags: winapi

How I can work with keyboard via Win Api? I need check specific keyboard key for these things: hold, press, release. I can't use Windows Message, just only Win API function. I already done check hold:

```
bool result;
result=false;
if(GetAsyncKeyState(MapVirtualKey(code,MAPVK_VSC_TO_VK))==-32767) result=true;
return result;
```

How I can check press and check release?

Press is just single key down. Release is key up after key press

Comment: Please tell us more about what exactly you are trying to achieve. The answers will greatly depend on this information.

Answer (score 0):

A normal application should use the key and char messages when dealing with input in its own window.

If you need to track keyboard events outside of your thread or even system-wide then you should use a [low-level keyboard hook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

`GetAsyncKeyState` is not the best API to use to track key states over time, it just reports what the state is right now. You cannot poll it in a tight loop and guarantee that you never miss a key event. You should also use a `< 0` check (or `& 0x8000`) to see if the key is down, not `==`.

`GetKeyState` is useful if you need to check the state of Ctrl/Shift/Alt when processing a input message.

Comment: I was done keyboard checking via WM_KEYDOWN and WM_KEYUP messages.